# The behaviour of fork() is not clear in this example

Tags: c, unix

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main(void)

{

pid_t pid;
switch(pid =fork())

 {


case -1:

perror("fork"); /* something went wrong */
exit(1);
/* parent exits */


case 0:
printf(" This is the child process mention in case 0 of switch!, but why case 0 reached?\n");


default:
printf("default case: pid returned by fork is %d\n",pid );

 }
return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
root@heena:/home/heena/fork# ./a.out 
default case: pid returned by fork is 4640
root@heena:/home/heena/fork#  This is the child process mention in case 0 of switch!, but why case 0 reached?
default case: pid returned by fork is 0
```

after that i had to press enter to get to the prompt.

Why case 0 is working when the case is default. Also how the command prompts comes automatically second time and executes the case 0?  and then why default comes again in the last?

Comment: Then what is the use of `fork()`?

Comment: when we fork as above, the two process will run in parallel?

Comment: Where is break statement

Comment: yes the processes will run in parallel. Generally It is customery to wait for the child process to finish before exiting the parent.

Answer (score 4):

This has little to do with `fork` and much to do with your `switch` statement.

Your child process returns from `fork` with a `0` return code so it goes into the `case 0`. Unfortunately, it then carries on down to `default` since you do not have a `break` statement at the end of the `case 0`. That's because the default behaviour at the end of a `case` is simply to fall through to the next `case` if there is one.

It's no different to:

```
int i = 1;
switch (i) {
    case 1:  puts ("It was one");
    case 2:  puts ("It was two");
    case 3:  puts ("It was three");
    default: puts ("It was something else");
}
```

which will end up with the seemingly psychotic output:

```
It was one
It was two
It was three
It was something else
```

To fix it (your code, not my sample above), use:

```
switch (pid =fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror ("fork");
        exit (1);  // will exit rather than fall through.
    case 0:
        printf (" This is the child process\n");
        break;     // will end switch rather than fall through.
    default:
        printf ("default case: pid returned by fork is %d\n",pid );
                   // nothing needed here since switch is ending anyway.
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are confused by the output:
for the Parent Process, it goes to `default` and prints the pid, then exits as you are not waiting for the child to finish. And you see the command prompt.
You see this:

> root@heena:/home/heena/fork# ./a.out
>   default case: pid returned by fork is 4640
>  root@heena:/home/heena/fork#

for the Child Process, `case 0` is executed, and prints the line, then **as there is no `break` statement after this case**, it goes to the default case and prints the pid of this (i.e. child) process which is 0, and then exits.
 So you see this:

> This is the child process mention in case 0 of switch!, but why case 0
>   reached?
>  default case: pid returned by fork is 0

Just insert `break;` after the `case 0:` and the output will be clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a break in case 0